# Access LDAP properties in Wildfly

Tags: ldap, wildfly

We are using the LdapLoginModule in our Wildfly 8.1.0 setup:

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" flag="sufficient">
    <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://????/"/>
    <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=company,DC=com"/>
    <module-option name="matchOnUserDN" value="false"/>
    <module-option name="principalDNSuffix" value="@domain.com"/>
    ....
</login-module>
```

Is it possible to access the properties (such as principalDNSuffix) from the code, e.g. in a stateless bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WildFly management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/The+native+management+API) to read the configuration.

Or use an HTTP client in your Java code and do similar call to this one:

```
curl --digest -u fred:fred.1234 -L -D - \
  http://localhost:9990/management \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "address" : [{ "subsystem" : "security" },
                 { "security-domain" : "your-security-domain" },
                 { "login-module" : "org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" },
                ],
    "operation" : "read-resource",
    "json.pretty":1
  }'
```

It connects to HTTP management interface and submits the `read-resource` operation as JSON object. (If you use WildFly `add-user` script to configure management users, then use DIGEST authentication. If your management users come from LDAP, use BASIC authentication).